# BASH script: how to use variable for $HOME in rc.local on start up

Tags: bash, autostart

I am executing a shell script which is referenced in rc.local. The file is git-versioned and needs to change into the respective home directory of each user. Absolute paths work fine, but those are different from machine to machine. $HOME or ~/ are not defined yet, how can I change into the main user's directory in rc.local on start-up?

This is the working script:

> cd /home/username/rightDIR
>
> php -S localhost:8000

This script starts the server but fails to move into the right directory beforehand:

> cd $HOME/rightDIR
>
> php -S localhost:8000

Comment: Who do you mean by "the main user"? `$HOME` is set, and `~` will use the current value of `$HOME`, but they will both refer to the root user's home directory, as `root` is the user that executes `rc.local`.

Comment: I mean the user that will be logging in, once the machine has start up (e.g. myself), so maybe I should rephrase: how can I cd into the users directory even though the script is executed by root where HOME is different. (there will only be one user on each system)

Comment: Again, what user? Machines can have multiple users, and *none* of them are logged in at the point `rc.local` is executed. Other than `root`, there is no notion of any other distinguished user. If there is a specific non-root user involved with a startup procedure, you have to be explicit in the scrip about who that is. The machine can't *guess* who will be logging in once startup is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd /home/*/rightDIR && php -S localhost:8000 &` should work if only one user has a `rightDIR` in their home folder (otherwise the first match wins).

The `&&` chains the commands together. If the `cd` command fails, the command after won't be started.

The `&` at the end starts the command as shell job in the background, so that the shell can continue and run any commands that come after this line in rc.local

If startup hangs anyway, consider adding `nohup` left of `php` instead, in order to detach the command from the shell.

Comment: Very smart workaround, and in my use-case: the target folder exists only once, it works very well!

Comment: Glad to help :)
If there is ever more than 1 such folder you could also loop through all /home/*/rightDIR and either check contents or even start up a webserver for each :)